# php: correct logic to use for sending email w/ checkboxes

Tags: checkbox, php

I have a simple contact form on my website that sends an email to different email addresses (different physical offices and email accounts) DEPENDING on which checkboxes the user fills out.

There are two checkboxes, one NMB and one MB for the values.

Here is what I want to do:
If one checkbox (NMB) is checked, send email to addy1
If one checkbox (MB) is checked, send to email addy2
If BOTH checkboxes (NMB and MB) is checked, send email to BOTH

SO, so far, I have this, but I suspect that its not going to work, or will send multiple emails....

```
    $office  = $_POST['office'];

    if  ($office == "NMB" ){
        $address = "adyy1@narf.com";
    }
    elseif  ($office == "MB" ){
        $address = "adyy2@narf.com";
    }
    elseif  ($office == "NMB"  && $office == "MB" ){
        $address = "addy1@narf.com,addy2@narf.com";
    }
```

I feel I am close, but without a cigar.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: what does your html code look like?

Comment: What is not working? the sending of the email? Or the if-else statement? What have you done to debug the code? What error do you get? Which mail class do you use? Or is it much earlier in the process: does the html not send the right information.. etc etc etc etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, but I am not sure what the names are for your checkboxes.  You can replace `cb1` and `cb2` with the respective checkbox names.

```
if  ($_POST['cb1'] == "NMB"  && $_POST['cb2']=='MB'){
    $address = "addy1@narf.com,addy2@narf.com";
}else if($_POST['cb1']=="NMB"){
    $address = "adyy1@narf.com";
}else if($_POST['cb2'] == "MB" ){
    $address = "adyy2@narf.com";
}
```

Comment: Ohhhh so each checkbox should be posted differently and have different names.   seems logical enough. haha

Answer (score 0):

Your checkbox value would be whatever your value attribute is set to, and the array key, that of your name attribute.

If you set $office = $_POST['checkbox'], you are all set if you value's are 'NMB' and 'MB'.

Answer (score 0):

I would have the HTML like this:

```
<form method=POST>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb_NMB" id="cb_NMB" value=1 /><label for="cb_NMB">NMB</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="cb_MB" id="cb_MB" value=1 /><label for="cb_MB">MB</label>
</form>
```

and then the PHP:

```
$addr = array();
if(isset($_POST['cb_NMB']))
    $addr[] = 'adyy1@narf.com';
if(isset($_POST['cb_MB']))
    $addr[] = 'adyy2@narf.com';

$message = '<b>Form Submitted</b><br />The form was submitted.';
foreach($addr as $a)
    mail($a,'Form Submission Notice',$message,"Content-type: text/html\r\n");
```

I use isset because $_POST['cb_NMB'] will not be set if the box is not checked and PHP will throw a warning.